# Parse Error [empty string] - W3C CSS Validator bug due to CSS size?

Tags: css, w3c, validation, parse-error

I have a problem with the following css validation:

http://www.provincia.le.it/html/portal/css.jsp

- If I try to validate using "**Validate by URI**", I get a "**Parse Error [empty string]**";
- If I try to validate using "**Validate by direct input**" by pasting the output of the browser for the uri *http://www.provincia.le.it/html/portal/css.jsp* I get "**Validation OK**";
- If I try to validate using "**Validate by file upload**" by choosing a file on local computer that is the output of the command '*wget http://www.provincia.le.it/html/portal/css.jsp*' I get "**Validation OK**";

Do you think this is a bug of the validator?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the validator is looking for a file with .css extension.

[image]

Comment: I’m not sure about that. The validator seems to load a reasonable amount of the file. It does seem like it’s being cut off.

Comment: Plus I’ve re-posted the stylesheet on my own website with a .jsp extension, and the validator seems fine with that version: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pauldwaite.co.uk%2Ftest-pages%2F8402272%2Fcss.jsp&profile=css21&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en

Comment: I Agree with Paul, Validator shouldn't mind about file extension

Answer (score 0):

Odd. I’ve reposted the stylesheet you linked to on my own website, with both .css and .jsp file extensions (both served as `text/css`), and the W3C validator seems happy to validate it from there:

- http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pauldwaite.co.uk%2Ftest-pages%2F8402272%2Fcss.css&profile=css21&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en
- http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pauldwaite.co.uk%2Ftest-pages%2F8402272%2Fcss.jsp&profile=css21&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en

It’s as if your server is not sending the entire stylesheet to the validator. Very odd.

Comment: but why the server should behave in different way when the page is requested from the validator? it should be an http request like the one made from browser, doesn't it?

Comment: Yeah, you would have thought so. If you have access to your server’s logs, you might be able to have a look at the request that comes from the validator, see if there’s anything weird about it or the server’s response.

Comment: Speculatively, it might be that the validator has a very aggressive timeout policy, so that if your server is even a little bit slow at sending the response, it just stops listening and validates whatever it’s received so far. But that’s utter guesswork on my part — I don’t even know if it makes technical sense.

Comment: I had a look also to the firewall log (between my server and validator server) and I notice that something strange happened... After the first request the validator try to establish new connections trying to send several SYN packet until it close the connection due to timeout. Do you think this can be due to the import made in css.jsp file that is a file of liferay that imports several other css?

Comment: @Aldo: oh, maybe. I can’t see any `@import` statements in css.jsp though.

Comment: because the css.jsp is elaborated by the server and then sent to the client that's why you don't see the import commands. I write here some lines of css.jsp file:  <%@ include file="/html/portlet/css_init.jsp" %>

<%@ page import="com.liferay.portal.model.ModelHintsConstants" %>

<%@ include file="/html/portal/aui/css.jspf" %>

<%@ include file="/html/portal/css/portal/generic_portal.jspf" %>
.....

Comment: @Aldo: oh — well, that won’t be to do with your JSP imports — as you say, they’re run on the server. The validator never sees those.

Comment: The strange thing is that this problem came up after an upgrade from liferay 6.0.5 to liferay 6.0.6 on the same server and same network configuration, that's why I was supposing this connection problem can be due to something strange that happen on the tomcat where is deployed the new version of liferay.... it is really odd!

Comment: Aha. Could be — might be worth posting a new question asking about Liferay serving CSS files. As far as I can tell, this isn’t a validator thing.

Comment: but if is not a validator thing, why when I ask the page through the browser or through wget command I manage to get the correct page? Doesn't the validator ask the page in the same way, through an HTTP request?

Comment: I assume so. If it *is* the validator, why does the validator work fine with the stylesheet served from my website? I guess it must be some interaction between the validator and your server (as the validator seems to work fine with the stylesheet served from my site).

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, is an interaction problem... it could be a great help to see the validator logs... in order to adreess the problem... I will make more test and let you know... thanks!